# Alternate Model Binding On Controllers Post Action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

`EDIT:` You can safely clone https://github.com/vslzl/68737969 and run the example. If you send

```
{
    "intPropB":3
}
```

as POST body to: http://localhost:5000/api/Test

you'll see it binds clearly B object to A object.

`#EDIT END`

I'd like to implement alternate model binding using `asp.net core 5` As you will see below, I have two alternative classes to bind at a single endpoint. Each request can contains only a valid A model or B model and A and B has different properties.

```
    [HttpPost(Name = Add)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var aModel= new A();
        var bModel= new B();
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<A>(aModel))
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Model binded to A");
            return Ok(aModel);
        }
        else if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<B>(bModel))
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Model binded to B");
            return Ok(bModel);
        }
        _logger.LogDebug("Nothing binded!");
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

But this approach failed. Is there a proper way to implement this kind of solution?

By the way I'm using this to reduce complexity of my endpoints, I want to update a record partially and by doing this, each model will map the same record but with different logics.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please include a minimum working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @abdusco here you are, really simple one.

Comment: Hi @vslzl, your code is not related to your post data. TryUpdateModelAsy here is just bind the new instance with default value, it will not update to the model with your post data. And CancellationToken is never used here.

Comment: @Rena yes actually official docs says TryUpdateModelAsync is not proper to use it in API endpoint that consumes JSON, it's designed to work with formdata. But I'm asking and wanted to demonstrate what I want to acquire. Also Cancellation token will be used in the actual project, this is just a demonstration. It'll be great if you can provide any suggestion.

Comment: Also I solved this issue by generating a model which contains an A object and a B Object as properties and redesigned the post data a little. But this solution seems childish to me. I think there should be more appropriate solutions out there.

Comment: Actually combine with your description and code, it seems you want to dynamically bind the posted data to model?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't manage to provide elegant way to do this but here is what I've done so far, It works but seems a little ugly in my opinion.

I changed the action method to this:

```
[HttpPost(Name = Add)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AddSync([FromBody] JObject body)
{  
    var aModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(body.ToString());
    var bModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(body.ToString());
    
    ModelState.Clear();
    var aValid = TryValidateModel(aModel);


    ModelState.Clear();
    var bValid = TryValidateModel(bModel);           

    // some logic here...
    return Ok(new {aModel,bModel, aValid, bValid });
}
```

I think It's not a good idea to interfere with ModelState this way.

But here is what I've done,

1. get the raw body of the request as `JObject` (requires `Newtonsoft.Json` package)
2. Parsed that json value to candidate objects
3. Check their validity via modelstate and decide which one to use.